# IBOutlet not connecting to uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I have a `UITableView` and I also have a `UITableViewCell` in my interface. Now I try to create an outlet for `UITableViewCell` in my class and I connect it to the interface the normal way anyone would. When i run it, it fails giving the error could not compile connection :

```
ibcocoatouchoutletconnection : 87q50w485w < IBProxyObject : 9u7-25whnsk> => UIViewTableViewCell => <IBUIViewTableCell>, where uiViewTableCell is the name for my IBoutlet.
```

I have been stuck with this for a while so any help would be appreciated. Theres hardly any help online for this error as well.

Comment: Why would you need an `IBOutlet` unless you are subclassing `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I want to be able to change the properties of a UITABLEviewcell in the interface builder. The only way i can do so is if i have an iboutlet connected to the program right?

Comment: No, you need to subclass UITableViewCell. If not, you can only change (some) properties of UITableViewCell in code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you declaring your property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myTableViewCell
```

Looks like you are declaring it like `IBUIViewTableCell`.

Comment: No. I did declare it the way you have declared it :(

Answer (score 0):

You are Not need to connect Outlet For TableviewCell. Jsut GO To IB.

-> Click On TableviewCell

-> Go to Identity Inspector

-> In Class Property inseatd of Tableviewcell Choose Your CustomCell Calss Out there.

-> Now You Can Customize Your tableview Cell.